# JavaScript current page identification

Tags: javascript

I have written the following code for identifying the current page and marking it accordingly in the navigation bar. It works perfectly, except for the first time index.php is loaded (the code is located at the end of header.php file:

```
 path = location.pathname.split("/"); 
 pathname= "#header_nav li a[href='" + path[(path.length-1)] + "']";
 $(pathname).attr("id","current");
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page's URL is http://domain/ instead of http://domain/index.php you won't match an a-element with href="index.php".

How about this?

```
var filename = location.pathname.split('/').pop();
var currentHref = filename ||'index.php';
$('#header_nav li a[href="' + currentHref + '"]').prop('id','current');
```

Keep in mind that in jQuery 1.6+ you should refer to the id attribute using the prop() function istead of attr(). I'd prefer using a classname, current, for this, though.

Comment: thanks, you were indeed right. it didn't have the index.php suffix. as for class vs. id, i figured since there is only one current page, it would make sense using an id.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your code inside jQuery's `.ready()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    path = location.pathname.split("/"); 
    pathname= "#header_nav li a[href='" + path[(path.length-1)] + "']";
    $(pathname).attr("id","current");
});
```